# How can I extract values in parentheses from a Python list using a regex?

Tags: python, regex

This is the data as a list:

```
states = ['Alabama (AL)', 'Alaska (AK)', 'Arizona (AZ)', 'Arkansas (AR)', 'California (CA)', 'Colorado (CO)', 'Connecticut (CT)', 'Delaware (DE)', 'District of Columbia (DC)', 'Florida (FL)', 'Georgia (GA)', 'Hawaii (HI)', 'Idaho (ID)', 'Illinois (IL)', 'Indiana (IN)', 'Iowa (IA)', 'Kansas (KS)', 'Kentucky (KY)', 'Louisiana (LA)', 'Maine (ME)', 'Maryland (MD)', 'Massachusetts (MA)', 'Michigan (MI)', 'Minnesota (MN)', 'Mississippi (MS)', 'Missouri (MO)', 'Montana (MT)', 'Nebraska (NE)', 'Nevada (NV)', 'New Hampshire (NH)', 'New Jersey (NJ)', 'New Mexico (NM)', 'New York (NY)', 'North Carolina (NC)', 'North Dakota (ND)', 'Ohio (OH)', 'Oklahoma (OK)', 'Oregon (OR)', 'Pennsylvania (PA)', 'Rhode Island (RI)', 'South Carolina (SC)', 'South Dakota (SD)', 'Tennessee (TN)', 'Texas (TX)', 'Utah (UT)', 'Vermont (VT)', 'Virginia (VA)', 'Washington (WA)', 'West Virginia (WV)', 'Wisconsin (WI)', 'Wyoming (WY)']
```

I want to extract all the codes in parentheses.

This code returned `None`:

```
re.search('[(A-Z)]')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you understand that what you have there is a list of strings, not a single string?    The regex "[A-Z][A-Z]" will work, but you'll need to apply it to each string in the list, one at a time.  Given that code, it would be more efficient just to do `codes = [k[-3:-1] for k in states]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=\()[A-Z]+(?=\))"
print(re.findall(regex, "".join(states)))
```

**Output:**

```
['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY']
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a list, you probably don't need a regex.  If you're guaranteed that's the format, something like this should do it:

```
abbreviations = [state[-3:-1] for state in states]
```

That code uses a [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to make a new list from your old list.  For each item in the `states` list, we're using [negative indexes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_negative_indexing.asp) (which start at the back of the string) and the [slice operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) to pull out the abbreviations since they're always the 2nd to last and 3rd to last characters in the strings.

Sample usage:

```
>>> states = ['Alabama (AL)', 'Alaska (AK)', 'Arizona (AZ)', 'Arkansas (AR)', 'California (CA)']
>>> [state[-3:-1] for state in states]
['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA']
```

Comment: ok thanks it works for me the results are not in list so what we do after

Comment: What is the format of the result that you need?

Comment: if the resuls are strings